Error while installing google-chrome in Amazon Linux 2023
im getting the following error code while trying to download google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm in AL2023
Last metadata expiration check: 3:03:15 ago on Thu Jun 27 11:36:32 2024.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline does not have a compatible architecture
  - nothing provides ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.12)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
  - nothing provides libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) needed by google-chrome-stable-126.0.6478.126-1.x86_64 from @commandline
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

What could potentially be the problem here?
sudo dnf install ./google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

